# How to do multiple nested ui:param?

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, parameters, javabeans

I'm working on a project and I want to test how much I can do with templates in JSF. Right now I am working on parameters and I was wondering how you could template multiple parameters.

```xml
<h:outputText value="#{bean.getobject.action}"/>
```

And I would put parameters like so...

```xml
<ui:param name="bean" value="#{myBean}"/>
<ui:param name="getobject" value="object"/>
<ui:param name="action" value="action"/>
```

I tried it like this but I get an error `CDATA tags may not nest`.

Is it possible at all? If not, are there any alternatives?

Comment: It looks to me that the last `<ui:param>` has the same name and value, which I think would result in a circular reference. Why would you want to do that? The other examples look fine to me.

Comment: It's like... myBean.getPerson.lastName. Like when you are referring to an entity from a database.

Comment: And you want to put them in 3 `<ui:param>` tags, first param will be referred by the second one, second one referred by third one, and so on? Is that the kind of nesting you are referring to?

Comment: Well, yeah. I had hoped it would work...

Comment: It does not look like it in your example though, so that got me confused.

Comment: Sorry. I wanted it to look as generic as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can nest `<ui:param>` values. You just reference them as EL expressions, like this:

`<ui:param name="bean" value="#{myBean}"/>`
`<ui:param name="getobject" value="#{bean.object}"/>`
`<ui:param name="action" value="#{getobject.action}"/>`

Hope that answers your question.